# Trying to locate a Netflix Kids TV series with alien girl. Show was called "Near Zero"(?)

Tags: story-identification

I am having a difficult time remembering this one old series that I watched on Netflix kids when I first tried Netflix.

I remember that the title was around **Xero** since I remember that I thought that the title was **Near Zero.**

Some of the characters was this alien girl that looks like a human, female, teenager that has a backpack with her 24/7. This backpack is a armored lizard (That can stand on two of its feet) that need to be with her to recharge. I recall that there was a portal in the boiler room from a school (With no one in it usually) that allowed her to go into this dimension. These two boys, what their name is, I can't recall, followed her, if I remember correctly, and they went into the dimension.

In the real world, it was live action but in the dimension, it was a video game style. When a person went into the dimension, they got armor and a weapon. The two boys found the alien girl (that looks like a teenage girl) crouching down doing something (looking for the boss?) with the tech lizard right by her.

I remember that they went to a new level after season 1, where, if my memory serves me right, where they lost one of the boys that later appears as a orb of light that helps them occasionally (but not fighting).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberchase?

Answer (score 6):

This is [Zixx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zixx).

The description on Wikipedia tallies nicely:

> The show consists of a mixture of live action "real world" sequences
>   interspersed with computer-generated scenes set inside a virtual
>   realm. In Zixx Level One, Elliott Digital used a game engine to create
>   the animation, the first time this was done for a television show.
>
> Flanngo: Zixx's investigative partner and mentor for several eons, he
>   is a cynical, wise-cracking thick-skinned detective from the same
>   planet as Zixx. While Zixx is the brains of the pair, Flanngo is the
>   brawn; he's fast, tenacious and like Zixx, someone you don't want to
>   mess with. He is surly and has the appearance of a theropod dinosaur.
>   He tends not to use inventory or weapons other than shields,
>   preferring his natural bodily abilities. In level 1, Flanngo can't go
>   outside the Keep, except inside Zixx's backpack, because breathing
>   Earth's air is toxic to him. However, in Level 2, Flanngo couldn't
>   leave the Keep until he was accidentally ejected from the Keep in the
>   form of a teenage boy in a dragon costume.

Comment: ................. 0o0 .......... THANK YOU

Comment: @thediamondranger - Don't forget to upvote and mark this answer as 'accepted'.

Comment: Ok but I can't find anything to play Zixx on :/

Comment: @TheDiamondRanger - I think you'll struggle. There's a longer clip here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5COvg0jt60w